# LSM9DS1: Inconsistent data form an accelerometer

Tags: pi-3, i2c, sensor, android-things

I'm currently getting inconsistent data from the accelerometer of my Adafruit LSM9DS1. To be more precise I either get a value close to the correct gravity (eg. 9.496515) or some reading like it was in space (eg. -0.023928225).

This seems to happen on all three the axes (I tried rotating the LSM9DS1).

I get the same behavior with FIFO enabled or not.

This is a set of 32 consecutive samples that I read from the FIFO memory:

```
result = {float[32][]@5092} 
 0 = {float[3]@5100} 
  0 = -0.41754755
  1 = 0.19501504
  2 = 9.519247
 1 = {float[3]@5112} 
  0 = -0.421735
  1 = 0.19980069
  2 = 9.51805
 2 = {float[3]@5120} 
  0 = -0.4229314
  1 = 0.20757735
  2 = 9.510274
 3 = {float[3]@5128} 
  0 = -0.4127619
  1 = 0.2207379
  2 = 9.502497
 4 = {float[3]@5139} 
  0 = -0.39302114
  1 = -0.06580262
  2 = -0.0017946169
 5 = {float[3]@5140} 
  0 = -0.06939186
  1 = -0.045463633
  2 = -0.020937197
 6 = {float[3]@5141} 
  0 = -0.05742774
  1 = -0.03469593
  2 = -0.0317049
 7 = {float[3]@5142} 
  0 = -0.053838514
  1 = -0.039481573
  2 = -0.041874394
 8 = {float[3]@5143} 
  0 = -0.054436717
  1 = -0.052642096
  2 = -0.043669015
 9 = {float[3]@5144} 
  0 = -0.059820566
  1 = -0.068793654
  2 = -0.03469593
 10 = {float[3]@5145} 
  0 = -0.06819545
  1 = 0.22731815
  2 = -0.019142581
 11 = {float[3]@5146} 
  0 = -0.38644087
  1 = 0.2225325
  2 = -0.00418744
 12 = {float[3]@5147} 
  0 = -0.40079778
  1 = 0.21535406
  2 = 9.505488
 13 = {float[3]@5148} 
  0 = -0.40977085
  1 = 0.21355942
  2 = 9.525827
 14 = {float[3]@5149} 
  0 = -0.40917268
  1 = 0.21296123
  2 = 9.540783
 15 = {float[3]@5150} 
  0 = -0.40558344
  1 = 0.2207379
  2 = 9.5455675
 16 = {float[3]@5151} 
  0 = -0.39960137
  1 = 0.22671993
  2 = 9.544371
 17 = {float[3]@5152} 
  0 = -0.39302114
  1 = 0.22791636
  2 = 9.534203
 18 = {float[3]@5153} 
  0 = -0.3906283
  1 = 0.21535406
  2 = 9.517452
 19 = {float[3]@5154} 
  0 = -0.38584265
  1 = 0.19441684
  2 = 9.496515
 20 = {float[3]@5155} 
  0 = -0.384048
  1 = 0.17347965
  2 = -0.023928225
 21 = {float[3]@5156} 
  0 = -0.38883367
  1 = 0.15553348
  2 = -0.042472597
 22 = {float[3]@5157} 
  0 = -0.39541394
  1 = -0.014356935
  2 = -0.05802595
 23 = {float[3]@5158} 
  0 = -0.40259242
  1 = -0.026919257
  2 = -0.06580262
 24 = {float[3]@5159} 
  0 = -0.40977085
  1 = -0.03589234
  2 = -0.071186475
 25 = {float[3]@5160} 
  0 = -0.4151547
  1 = -0.040677987
  2 = -0.062213387
 26 = {float[3]@5161} 
  0 = -0.421735
  1 = -0.03888337
  2 = -0.04965107
 27 = {float[3]@5162} 
  0 = -0.42831525
  1 = -0.040677987
  2 = -0.032303106
 28 = {float[3]@5163} 
  0 = -0.4372883
  1 = -0.04426722
  2 = -0.014356935
 29 = {float[3]@5164} 
  0 = -0.445065
  1 = -0.04785645
  2 = 9.496515
 30 = {float[3]@5165} 
  0 = -0.44865423
  1 = -0.04666004
  2 = 9.503693
 31 = {float[3]@5166} 
  0 = -0.44865423
  1 = -0.04426722
  2 = 9.506086
```

As you can see 15 times the Z axis shows the correct value and 17 shows -0.

This is how I'm initializing the sensors:

```
        // soft reset & reboot accel/gyro
        writeRegByte(SensorType.XG, REGISTER_CTRL_REG8, (byte) 0b00000101);
        // soft reset & reboot magnetometer
        writeRegByte(SensorType.MAG, REGISTER_CTRL_REG2_M, (byte) 0b00001100);

        SystemClock.sleep(10);

        byte idXg = readRegByte(SensorType.XG, REGISTER_WHO_AM_I_XG);
        byte idMag = readRegByte(SensorType.MAG, REGISTER_WHO_AM_I_M);
        if (idXg != XG_ID || idMag != MAG_ID) {
            throw new IllegalStateException("Could not find LSM9DS1, check wiring!");
        }

        setFifoMemoryEnabled(false);

        // enable gyro continuous
        writeRegByte(SensorType.XG, REGISTER_CTRL_REG1_G, (byte) 0b11000000); // on XYZ

        // Enable the accelerometer continuous
        writeRegByte(SensorType.XG, REGISTER_CTRL_REG5_XL,
                (byte) (CTRL_REG5_XL_ZEN_XL | CTRL_REG5_XL_YEN_XL | CTRL_REG5_XL_XEN_XL)); // enable X Y and Z axis
        writeRegByte(SensorType.XG, REGISTER_CTRL_REG6_XL, (byte) 0b11000000); // 1 KHz out data rate, BW set by ODR, 408Hz anti-aliasing
        writeRegByte(SensorType.XG, REGISTER_CTRL_REG7_XL, (byte) 0b10000000); // HR - High resolution mode

        // enable mag continuous
        writeRegByte(SensorType.MAG, REGISTER_CTRL_REG3_M, (byte) 0x00); // continuous mode
```

And this is how I'm reading the accelerometer data:

```
        byte[] buffer = new byte[6];
        int[] result = new int[3];
        readRegBuffer(SensorType.XG, REGISTER_OUT_X_L_XL, buffer, buffer.length);
        result[0] = (buffer[1] << 8) | buffer[0]; // Store x-axis values
        result[1] = (buffer[3] << 8) | buffer[2]; // Store y-axis values
        result[2] = (buffer[5] << 8) | buffer[4]; // Store z-axis values
        return result;
```

I'm then converting the raw values with this formula (but this is a constant change so it should not matter):

```
rawAccelerometerData[i] * mAccelMgLsb / 1000f * mGravity;
```

I've also tried to disable the gyro and the magnetometer and left only the Z axis enabled and than tried to fetch the data using different output data rate but the result is the same.

The full code of my driver is available [here](https://github.com/leinardi/androidthings-drivers/blob/lsm9ds1/driver-lsm9ds1/src/main/java/com/leinardi/androidthings/driver/lsm9ds1/Lsm9ds1.java).

I currently have only one LSM9DS1 so **I have no clue if this is a defective product or an expected behavior and if this can be fixed with a different configuration**.

Comment: Reading through the [data sheet](http://www.st.com/content/ccc/resource/technical/document/datasheet/1e/3f/2a/d6/25/eb/48/46/DM00103319.pdf/files/DM00103319.pdf/jcr:content/translations/en.DM00103319.pdf) (i.e. ___rtfm___ ing) suggests that if the accelerometer and the gyroscope are both enabled then the data readout can contain both gyroscope data followed by/alternating with accelerometer data.  Now I haven't looked into you code in too much detail but have you configure the device to fit with your code - it sounds possible that you have not...

Comment: Hi @SlySven thanks for the hint, I tried to disable the gyro (writing 0 to `CTRL_REG1_G`), but nothing changes, I still get ½ time 0 and ½ time 1G on Z axis of the accelerometer. Anyway the gyro and accelerometer use 2 different registers to read the data (`OUT_X_L_G` and `OUT_X_L_XL`) and I can correctly see that when the gyro is disabled I get only zeros from the G register. I was not able to find the place in the datasheet where is stated that I can get mixed data when you have both enabled, could you please point me to the right page?

Comment: Check Section "3 LSM9DS1 functionality" on page 19 of 72 about enabling/disabling the Gyroscope (Angular acceleration!) and Section "3.3 Accelerometer and gyroscope multiple reads (burst)" on page 21...

Comment: I went through those sections but I haven't found anything about getting unreliable data when both gyro and accel are enabled. This is what says about reading when both are enabled: "When both accelerometer and gyroscope sensors are activated at the same ODR, starting from OUT_X_G (18h - 19h) multiple reads can be performed. Once OUT_Z_XL (2Ch - 2Dh) is read, the system automatically restarts from OUT_X_G (18h - 19h)". But, anyway, as I said I tried also with only the Accelerometer enabled and the problem is still present.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is how the accelerometer data is read, to be precise is in these lines:

```
result[0] = (buffer[1] << 8) | buffer[0]; // Store x-axis values
result[1] = (buffer[3] << 8) | buffer[2]; // Store y-axis values
result[2] = (buffer[5] << 8) | buffer[4]; // Store z-axis values
```

What I'm getting from the sensor is a 16bit in two’s complement spitted in 2 bytes, for example `buffer[4]` and `buffer[5]` where 4 is the low byte and 5 is the high.

In Java the `&` and `|` are defined to operate only on `int` and `long` values, so what happens is that the `byte` is always promoted to signed `int`:

```
buffer[5] = 00111100 
buffer[4] = 11110110
(int)buffer[4] = 11111111111111111111111111110110 = FF FF FF F6
(buffer[5] << 8) | buffer[4] = FF FF FF F6
```

With the original code both bytes are handled has two’s complement when actually **only the high byte is holding the sign**.

Long story short, you have to keep the sign for the high byte (cast to `int`) and threat the low as unsigned (autocast to `int` using the `&` and keeping only the original byte with `0xFF`):

```
result[0] = (((int) buffer[1]) << 8) | (buffer[0] & 0xFF); // Store x-axis values
result[1] = (((int) buffer[3]) << 8) | (buffer[2] & 0xFF); // Store y-axis values
result[2] = (((int) buffer[5]) << 8) | (buffer[4] & 0xFF); // Store z-axis values
```

Comment: Would you benefit from tweaking the **BLE** (Big/Little Endian) bit in the **CTRL_REG8** (22h) to swap to Big Endian mode so that the 16 bits of data are in the _right_ order to be mapped into a `int16_t` ...?

Comment: This is actually an interesting point: I tried it out and if I enable it I can actually use the `readRegWord()` to read 2 bytes and map it into a `short` (16 bit int in Java) so, no manual bit shifting needed. the problem is that than I had to split the single read that I do of the 6 bytes in 3 separate reads, one per each axis and I'm not sure if this will be the worth since I fear it would be slightly less performant and since the current code is now working correctly... But it would make the code for sure more readable.